# Infinite random sequence loops with randomIO but not with getRandom

Tags: haskell, random, lazy-evaluation, infinite, evaluation-strategy

I'm having difficulty trying to figure out a way to reason about why the following two, seemingly equivalent definitions of an infinite random number sequence (`inf` and `inf'`) are evaluated completely differently:

```
import Control.Monad.Random (Rand, evalRandIO, getRandom)
import System.Random        (Random, RandomGen, randomIO)

inf :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => Rand g [a]
inf = sequence (repeat getRandom)

inf' :: (Random a) => IO [a]
inf' = sequence (repeat randomIO)

-- OK
main = do
  i <- evalRandIO inf
  putStrLn $ show $ take 5 (i :: [Int])

-- HANGS
main' = do
  i <- inf'
  putStrLn $ show $ take 5 (i :: [Int])
```

when called, `main'` terminates and prints 5 random integers, whereas `main` loops infinitely — what causes `sequence . repeat` to be evaluated differently on `getRandom` than it does on `randomIO`?

Comment: You mean `main` terminates and `main'` hangs?

Comment: @AndrásKovács yes, exactly.

Comment: There's an important difference between the two. `evalRandIO` uses `IO` to get the initial generator, generating an infinite list from this doesn't require any more IO. `randomIO` requires an `IO` call for every random number, so it hangs when it tries to return in infinite list (unless you use `unsaveInterleaveIO`).

Comment: @cchalmers: how would you use unsafeInterleaveIO in this case? I tried but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @ErikAllik I don't think you can use it with `sequence` because `sequence` already demands the full list. It works with something like `inf = do {r <- randomIO; rs <- unsafeInterleaveIO inf; return (r:rs)}`.

Answer (score 3):

Sequencing lists is strict in the IO monad but possibly lazy in the State monad. `Rand` is just a [wrapped `StateT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.4/docs/src/Control-Monad-Random.html#RandT), so it can be lazy:

```
type Rand g = RandT g Identity
newtype RandT g m a = RandT (StateT g m a)
```

`evalRandIO` queries the IO random number generator just once at the beginning, then runs the `State`-ful computation on the acquired `StdGen`:

```
evalRandT :: (Monad m) => RandT g m a -> g -> m a
evalRandT (RandT x) g = evalStateT x g

evalRand :: Rand g a -> g -> a
evalRand x g = runIdentity (evalRandT x g)

evalRandIO :: Rand StdGen a -> IO a
evalRandIO x = fmap (evalRand x) newStdGen
```

In contrast, `sequence $ repeat randomIO` contains an infinite number of side effecting IO actions, because each `randomIO` modifies the global random number generator. We can't inspect the return value until all the effects are performed. It's similar to doing `sequence $ repeat getLine`, which just reads lines repeatedly, and never returns.